# A reference book for Schur's lemma

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reference-request

We want to find the reference book for some version of the Schur's lemma which covers the following result

Let $A$ be an assoiative algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ with countable basis, then any central element acts on any simple $A$-module as a scalar.

Thanks

Comment: Why is it relevant that the algebra has a countable basis?

Comment: @André: Take $A = M = \mathbb{C}(x)$. Every element is central, but only a few act as scalars!

Comment: I'd bet it must be also in Dixmier's Universal eneveloping algebras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (an immediate consequence of) [Lemma 2.1.3(b) in Chriss-Ginzburg](http://books.google.com/books?id=lwS59rR78eIC&lpg=PA63&vq=Lemma%202.1.3&pg=PA62#v=snippet&q=Lemma%202.1.3&f=false).

Answer (score 4):

Doc, if you want to be anal with your references, you should quote
*Amitsur, A. S. Algebras over infinite fields. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 7 (1956), 35–48.*

Otherwise, this is a well-known fact and you can just refer to it as **"Amitsur's Trick"** or **"Noncommutative Nullstellensatz"**. Chapter 9 of McConnell-Robson-Noncommutative-Noetherian-Rings is devoted entirely to this property and its finer variations.

Answer (score 3):

From Wikipedia:

- David S. Dummit, Richard M. Foote. *Abstract Algebra*. 2nd ed., pg. 337.
- Lam, Tsit-Yuen (2001), *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings*, Berlin, New York: Springer-Verlag, ISBN 978-0-387-95325-0

From Google Books:

- William Fulton, Joe Harris. *Representation Theory*.
- William Arveson. *An Invitation to C*-Algebras*.

I hope that helps you a bit.

P.s: I wanted to post this in a comment, but the comment button isn't available for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, i only have the book of Lam in hand. However i don't find it yet.

Comment: Johan, just so you know, you need at least 50 reputation in order to leave comments on posts that are not your own. I imagine you will get there pretty soon, though!

Comment: @BR Aha! Well, You are right. I just passed that limit (-;

Answer (score 3):

This is also in Bourbaki's Algebra 8 (most recent edition), Section 3, number 2, Example, page 43.  This reference is online if you have access to SpringerLink.